# Scale a picture in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Currently I am trying to scale a picture in VBA, but cannot seem to get what I need. Every time I run though....

```
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("C:\\\Logo.bmp").Select
            With Selection
                  .ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 1.4, msoTrue
                  .ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 0.5, msoFalse
             End With
```

It will scale to the correct width initially, but then when I go to the next line and try to scale the height it changes the width. Can someone help me understand why this happens and suggest a better way of scaling the picture. I need it to be about 125% bigger in length and about 50% smaller in height.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Include this line:

```
.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
```

To allow both width and height being "unlocked", put it right on the top.

```
With Selection
    .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
    .ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 1.4, msoTrue
    .ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 0.5, msoFalse
End With
```

Comment: where? before or after i scale?

Comment: @PatrickWilson Depending upon what you want: on top of everything would allow both width and height being "completely free". After the Width, would make the height free altough the width will be linked to the original ratio... I guess that you want on top, will update my answer right now.

Comment: Nevermind. This works perfectly. I placed it before for anyone else with this problem

Answer (score -1):

In the ShapeRange.ScaleWidth and ScaleHeight methods, the RelativeToOriginalSize argument should be **msoFalse** if you **want** to scale it relatively (as in maintain aspect ratio, it will adjust width and height while scaling).  So if you **don't want** it to scale relatively, just set that argument to **msoTrue** for both:

```
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("C:\\\Logo.bmp").Select
With Selection
    .ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 1.4, msoTrue
    .ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 0.5, msoTrue
End With
```

Comment: The `RelativeToOriginalSize` arg doesn't control whether or not aspect ratio is maintained when scaling, it only specifies the reference, or "starting size" for the scaling operation.  (It should also be noted that `RelativeToOriginalSize` must always be `msoFalse` for all built-in shapes (i.e. those shapes which are not derived from imported image file objects).